# pdo parameter table name secure equivalent

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a set of code as such:

```
$table=(int)$_GET["table"];
$row=(int)$_GET["row"];
$prepare=$listingDatabase->prepare("select * from listing$table where row=? and login=?");
$prepare->execute(array($row,$login));
```

This code has `listing$table` where `$table` is filtered into an integer. I personally believe that (int) is not enough.

Is there a secure way to create table name as a parameter?

Comment: whitelist the table name instead

Comment: I was thinking about that. Is it possible to create a query: query("show tables where tablename=?")

Comment: you could do that, or just define an array with table names

Comment: If `$table` is to be an int, then you must know the appropriate range of integers (assuming they're contiguous). You could just validate `if ($table >= $minallowed && $table <= $maxallowed)`